# Checking if periodic ScheduledFuture is running now

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduling

I have a periodic task scheduled via Spring `TaskScheduler.schedule(Runnable, Trigger)`.

Given the returned `ScheduledFuture`, is there any way to check, if the task is running at current moment?

Comment: what would it mean if you call isRunning() and it returns true? I mean, there is no guarantee that if I call it again it would be true. What are you trying to achieve? Monitoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change you Runnable like this:

```
class Runner implements Runnable{
    public volatile boolean RUNNING = false;
        public void run(){

        RUNNING = true;
        try{
            // Your code
        } finally {
            RUNNING = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**edit**
Thought operations with `boolean` are atomic and don't need to be volatile.

Comment: running would need to be volatile

Comment: small clarification: boolean needs to be volatile to ensure not atomicity but visibility of change. This is part of Java Memory Model, as described by language spec.

Answer (score 8):

After a bit of testing,

```
public static boolean isRunning(ScheduledFuture future) {
    return future.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) <= 0;
}
```

works like a charm. Seems the task gets rescheduled only after completion, so `getDelay()` returns negative value.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check non-periodic future (java.util.concurrent.FutureTask) the solution with only

```
future.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) <= 0
```

doesn't work. You can't even combine

```
future.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) <= 0 && !future.isDone()
```

because `future.isDone()` returns true for all states except NEW which means "Scheduled". But if future is just started `future.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) <= 0 && !future.isDone()` never return true because not started future (NEW) never has negative delay

So I came up with pretty stupid simple solution and it works

```
future.isDone() && future.toString().startsWith("[Not completed]")
```

It's a bit ugly but does the job

Comment: for for my use case when I wanted to know if future is scheduled or running `future.toString().startsWith("[Not completed]")` was enough